# Converting SQL query to CodeIgniter query

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm having trouble finding a reliable solution for this query that I made in SQL server, now can somebody help me convert this query to codeigniter query, any help will be much appreciated

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s1.idnumber,
    s1.firstname,
    s1.middlename,
    s1.lastname,
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            SUM(s4.point) 
        FROM students s3 
        LEFT JOIN section_student s4 
        ON s3.id = s4.student_id
        WHERE s3.id = s1.id AND s4.schoolyear = s2.schoolyear AND s4.semester = s2.semester
    ) AS 'point'
FROM
students s1
LEFT JOIN section_student s2
ON s1.id = s2.student_id
WHERE s2.schoolyear = '2018-2019' AND s2.semester = '2nd'
GO
```

*Edited

[this is the result of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qswg5.png)

[and the structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwOr.png)

in trying to retrieve all the data within school year 2018-2019 and 2nd semester

Comment: Very hard to provide any kind of help without knowing your table structures, data, expected result/output, etc. That said, CI's query builder does not have methods for nested selects, so you'd need to build a hybrid of a regular SQL query and a query builder method (basically, the outermost query and its conditions are query builder-able and the nested one is not)

Comment: Does your query work?

Comment: this query works perfectly in sql svr

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
$this->db->select(" DISTINCT s1.idnumber,s1.firstname,s1.middlename,s1.lastname,(SELECT DISTINCT  SUM(s4.point)  FROM students s3  LEFT JOIN section_student s4  ON s3.id = s4.student_id WHERE s3.id = s1.id AND s4.schoolyear = s2.schoolyear AND s4.semester = s2.semester) AS point");
  $this->db->from('students s1');
  $this->db->join('section_student s2','s1.id = s2.student_id','left');
  $this->db->where('s2.schoolyear','2018-2019');
  $this->db->where('s2.semester','2nd');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  echo $this->db->last_query();die;//it will give you query please copy this and run in your db
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       return $query->result();
  } else {
       return array();
  }
```

Comment: did you compare your query with last_query? and can you show me the error what you get from CI method?

Comment: Remove the first SELECT because the method `select()` adds that keyword. So then `$this->db->select("SELECT DISTINCT...` becomes `$this->db->select("DISTINCT...`

Comment: yes, its pretty much the same. this was the error i got : A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 42000/102

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: i remove the first SELECT then again it has the same error

Comment: in the select statement provided by @M.Hemant remove the single quotes around `'point'` or escape them with backslashes (e.g. `\'point\'`), that should do the trick